# React Firebase, Document not being created

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am trying to register a user. After successfully using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and then uploading an image to its auth details, I want to create a users collection to store all user info. This is my code:

```js
//CREATE USER ACCOUNT
const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  auth,
  data.Email,
  data.Password
);

//UPLOAD IMAGE
const storageRef = ref(storage, `${data.Email}`);
if (profileIcon != undefined) {
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, profileIcon);
  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (error) => {
      setError(true);
      console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
        await updateProfile(user.user, {
          displayName: `${data.FirstName} ${data.LastName}`,
          photoURL: downloadURL,
        });
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.user.uid), {
          uid: user.user.uid,
          displayName: `${data.FirstName} ${data.LastName}`,
          firstName: data.FirstName,
          lastName: data.LastName,
          email: data.Email,
          photoUrl: downloadURL,
        });
      });
    }
  );
}
```

I wrote the `setDoc` function in there because I need the `downloadUrl` so I can add it to the doc. However I don't get any error and the document never gets created does anyone know why?

Comment: What sort of logging or step-through debugging have you done that helps you trace the actual execution of the code that doesn't seem to run? It's not enough to say "the document never gets created" - you should show that you know each line of code that runs, and which one in particular doesn't work the way you expect. Also if there are any errors, you should show them here. Every Firebase API call can result in an error.

Comment: I moved the SetDoc to outside of that scope and it creates the doc correctly, but the photoUrl is empty so i moved it into the scope and now its not being created at all

Comment: i also put that function inside a try catch and i still get no error

Comment: OK, please edit the question to share your debugging details including the logging you added that shows how the code is running, and the contents of all the relevant variables, especially the download url.

Comment: Check `user.user.uid`, what does that return?

Comment: i get the user id but i had to move the console log outside the getDownloadUrl scope as it didnt print anything when it was in there

Comment: FYI `\`${data.Email}\`` is a completely redundant template literal, just use `data.Email`. Also, assuming all names have a _first_ and _last_ name is prone to issues. See [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handling of [UploadTask.on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.uploadtask#uploadtaskon) has skipped the *nextObserver* which results in incorrect callback usage. The parameters are, in order...

> on(event, nextObserver, error, complete)

You can [treat the upload task like a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.uploadtask#uploadtaskthen) since you only seem interested in its completion or failure which would simplify your code quite a lot

```js
try {
  const uploadSnapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, profileIcon);
  const downloadUrl = await getDownloadUrl(uploadSnapshot.ref);

  await updateProfile(user.user, {
    displayName: `${data.FirstName} ${data.LastName}`,
    photoURL: downloadURL,
  });

  await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.user.uid), {
    uid: user.user.uid,
    displayName: `${data.FirstName} ${data.LastName}`,
    firstName: data.FirstName,
    lastName: data.LastName,
    email: data.Email,
    photoUrl: downloadURL,
  });
} catch (err) {
  setError(true);
  console.error(error);
}
```